# How to get extent of rasters in folder ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, raster, extents

I have 100 raster image in a folder and want to get extent of all raster in ArcGIS. How to get extents of all raster in one go or write in text file?

For single raster I used this is working fine:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
elevRaster = Raster('C:/arcgis/ArcTutor/3DAnalyst/Exercise2/workspace2/congrd')
myExtent = elevRaster.extent
print myExtent
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your raster folder as workspace, listrasters, loop over each raster and use describe to create [extent objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/extent.htm) witch has properties like XMin, YMin:

```
import arcpy

folder = r'C:\Test'
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

for r in rasterlist:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(r).extent
    print ext.XMin, ext.YMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMax #Dont know what you want to output
```

And if you have ArcMap >10.3 (?) you have pandas module which can be used to output a csv:

```
import pandas as pd    
data = []
for r in rasterlist:
    ext = arcpy.Describe(r).extent
    data.append([r, ext.XMin, ext.YMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMax])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['rastername','XMin','YMin','XMax','YMax'])
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=r'C:\Test\rasterextents.csv',index=False)
```

Example:

```
rastername,XMin,YMin,XMax,YMax
skeleton1.tif,291908.2252608799,6453910.748380102,293059.2252608799,6454910.748380102
zones.tif,292368.1635080902,6454595.5931031685,292585.77759756014,6454600.584252009
zones2.tif,292368.1635080902,6454595.5931031685,292629.6997073614,6454600.584252009
```

Comment: thanks It is working fine, how can we use for different imagery in different directory specially in ESRI grid format (Recursive) or folder can be set for different directory

Comment: Try [Walk](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm): "Generate data names in a directory/database structure by walking the tree top-down or bottom-up. Each directory/workspace yields a tuple of three: directory path, directory names, and file names."

Comment: Thanks a lot, It Walk suffice my purpose

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox